# Why does RegularExpressions.GroupCollection enumerable not work with Linq extension methods?

Tags: c#, linq

I was working with regular expressions in C# and when you test a regex you can obtain a list of captured groups, which is an instance of `System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection`.

All the stuff about regexes is not relevant. What is relevant is that I cannot query the instance of `GroupCollection` using LINQ extension methods (like `Where`, `First`, etc.), Visual Studio just tells me those method don't exist.

Initially I thought this was not a queryable type, however by peeking at the class declaration in Visual Studio, here's what it looks like:

```
public class GroupCollection : ICollection<Group>, IEnumerable<Group>, IEnumerable,
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Group>>, IList<Group>,
    IReadOnlyCollection<KeyValuePair<string, Group>>, IReadOnlyCollection<Group>,
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Group>, IReadOnlyList<Group>, ICollection, IList
{
    ...
}
```

Now, correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't LINQ be available on any `IEnumerable<T>` ? Am I just wrong in thinking that? What am I missing?

Comment: You added using System.Linq?

Comment: @IgorKovalev you've read the doc other way - IQueryable *has* Where/First as extension methods, it doesn't in any way imply that Where/First extension methods are available *only* for that interface.

Comment: Master_T - I've updated the title as it looks like the question (and answers) are very specific to this class (which is quite commonly used, so I think more specific title make the question more easily discoverable - feel free to revert/improve. Flag NLN when read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I didn't consider an important detail: the code I'm writing is part of a library that targets multiple versions of .NET:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0-windows;netcoreapp3.1;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

Apparently, in .NET 4.6.x the `GroupCollection` class does NOT implement `IEnumerable`, thus why the LINQ expressions are not available.

Visual Studio when peeking at internal framework code apparently shows you the definition of the first framework in the list, so I was seeing the definition for .NET 5

Comment: It implements IEnumerable but not IEnumerable<T>, required for linq methods. So add commented on the other answer, use Cast<Group>. The reason is that this class in the Net Franework is older than generics(like ArrayList).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to access the Values property.

```
GroupCollection c;

c.Values.Where ...
```

It is the values property that is an IEnumerable of Group.

P.S.  I see this for the declaration of GroupCollection:

```
public class GroupCollection : 
    IList<Group>, 
    IReadOnlyList<Group>, 
    IList, 
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Group>
```

Although IList should derive from IEnumerable, so, yup, also a little confused as to why we don't see Linq methods on the GroupCollection class.

Comment: "Although IList should derive from IEnumerable" if it was just implementing the non-generic interfaces, it would explain OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is not the solution but it made me understand the problem: the code I'm writing is a multi-target library (targets both .net461 and .net5) apparently GroupCollection only implements IENumerable in .net5 (same with the "Values" property you mention, is not presente in .net461). I guess I'll just have to use the classic foreach if I want to support the older farmeworks

Comment: @Master: no, you can use the Cast method to make it work. Just append...Cast<Group>() and you can use it like it was implementing the generic

Comment: Thanks, you're right, casting has the side-effect of converting the collection to an enumerable!

Comment: @Master: well, it's already IEnumerable but not IEnumerable<T> which most linq extension methods expect(apart from Cast and OfType).